# What do these jQuery statements mean or what do they do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

What exactly does the below jQuery statements mean or what do they do?

```
$(window).focus(mainWindowFocus);
$(window).unbind('focus', mainWindowFocus);
```

This is in relation to main window and a child/popup window.

```
function mainWindowFocus() {
    if (popUpWindow && !popUpWindow.closed) {
        popUpWindow.focus();
    } else {
         popUpWasClosed();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more code so we have an idea of what the mainWindowFocus variable is related to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(window).focus(mainWindowFocus);
```

This statement will bind the `focus event` to the `window` and attaches the function `mainWindowFocus` as event handler.

```
$(window).unbind('focus',mainWindowFocus);
```

This statement will explicitly remove the function `mainWindowFocus` from the event handlers for the `focus event`, which are bound to the `window`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more in simple terms..Actually $(window).unbind('focus',mainWindowFocus); is written under popUpWasClosed...But I want to know what exactly does it do or what is it used for?

Comment: @hmthur: I can't describe it much better. It removes an `event handler function` and that is the function `mainWindowFocus`. If you would just call `.unbind('focus');` it would remove **all** event handlers for that event.